# ¿ calcular el tiempo en horas minutos y segundos de diferentes aviones que van a distinta velocidad?

Tags: c

Tengo una función que me realiza el cambio a horas minutos y segundos, sin embargo, a la hora de mostrarlo por pantalla nos muestra los mismos minutos y segundos para todos los casos y 0 horas siempre. ¿Cual podría ser el error? La parte del código de la función sería la siguiente:

```
{
    double horasViaje, minutosViaje, segundosViaje;
    double tiempoViaje = (double)distanciaPais / (double)velocidadAvion; // tiempo de viaje en horas con decimales
    minutosViaje = modf(tiempoViaje, &horasViaje);
    minutosViaje = minutosViaje * 60; // convertimos las horas en minutos
    segundosViaje = modf(minutosViaje, &minutosViaje);
    segundosViaje = segundosViaje * 60; // convertimos los minutos en segundos
    modf(segundosViaje, &segundosViaje);

    char *infoViaje;
    sprintf(infoViaje, "%.0lfh:%.0lfm:%.0lfs", horasViaje, minutosViaje, segundosViaje);

    return infoViaje;
}
```

Comment: No has reservado memoria para infoViaje. Defines el puntero pero no le asignas memoria. Esto te va a producir una excepción como poco.

Comment: ¿Cuál es la unidad de `velocidadAvion`? ¿Km/h, MPH, m/s, tocino?

Answer (score 0):

No veo que en ningún lado estés calculando las horas de viaje. horasViaje es siempre 0, por eso nunca se hace ningún cálculo correcto. Quizá estés confundiendo las variables tiempoViaje y horasViaje.